# Largest eigenvalue of matrix A smaller than 1, what about B when A=B+C?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-radius

Suppose I have a square matrix $A$ that only has non-negative real entries and is **not** symmetric and not primitive either. It has no "special" structure we could exploit. I know that the spectral radius $\rho(A) <1$ (i.e. the maximum of the absolute eigenvalues of $A$ is smaller than $1$).

I now construct matrix $B$ by setting some of the entries of $A$ to zero (not specified how many or where they are). So we know the elementwise property that $A_{ij} \geq B_{ij} \geq 0$ for each $i,j$. We can also write the matrices as $A = B + C$ where the matrix $C$ contains the "deleted" values.

Is it possible to prove that if $\rho(A) <1$ then also $\rho(B) <1$?

---

Related postings:

- When we have symmetric matrices we can use [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179855/largest-eigenvalue-of-the-sum-of-hermitian-matrices).
- For primitive matrices there is a handwavy argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148718/frobenius-perron-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector-of-sum-of-two-matrices).
- we can work with the upper bound of the [row sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445740/the-maximum-eigenvalue-of-the-sum-of-two-matrix/445894#445894), but this did not give me the right result as it just provides an upper bound.

Comment: Within the cone of entry-wise positive matrices, the spectral radius is monotonous. This is a part of Perron-Frobeius theory. Thus $\rho(B)\le\rho(A)$, which solves your question. Have a look to my book **Matrices** (Springer-Verlag GTM 216) for instance.

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much! I used Lemma 12 on page 153 of your book as a reference.